# Change decimal separator on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am running the following in my Android application:

```
LocaleData data = LocaleData.get(desiredLocale);
```

to get the decimal separator.

Currently the variable `desiredLocale = 'es'` and returns the decimal separator as "," How can I get to get the decimal separator "."?

Comment: "," is the correct decimal separator for Spain. How are you specifying the Locale? If no country is set, it will assume a country. For example, `Locale("es")` produces a locale of `es_ES`, which uses a comma decimal separator. But if you specify `Locale("es", "MX")`, you will get a dot decimal separator.

Comment: when executing the code obtained in the variable 'locale' = 'is' but the separator you get is "," when the correct one should be "."

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying. The correct decimal separator for both Spain and Iceland is a comma. You can't specify a locale by language alone if you are trying to get the correct decimal separator. You also need a country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by configuring [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator('.');
```

Comment: Hola, no me llegó a funcionar por lo que agregué la siguiente linea 'LocaleHelper.setLocale(base,"en")' al inicio de ejecutarse el app.

Comment: DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();